# PFQueryTableViewController App crash after tableview reload

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

In my app i have a PFQueryTableViewController that shows a list of meetings. Tapping on a custom table view cell pushes a detailed view of the meeting itself and in this view the user can cancel the meeting through a button. I managed to implement two sections in the table view, one for meetings created by the current user and one for the others. The table view works fine and fetches my parse data correctly but if i enter the detailed view and cancel a meeting and then go back the the table view the app is terminated with an error. Same thing if i simply delete one of the meetings in the parse Core and then pull to refresh the table view. The error is this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -      [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c4703f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c109bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c35b4d3 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
3   SpeedMeet_1.0                       0x0000000107d28fbc -[PFQueryTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 167
4   UIKit                               0x000000010aabdcd3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
5   UIKit                               0x000000010aa9d7f1 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
6   UIKit                               0x000000010aab365c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
7   UIKit                               0x000000010aa40199 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000109b60f98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000109b55bbe _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109b55a2e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ac3ade _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ac4bea _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ac5255 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c3a5347 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c3a52a0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c39b0d3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c39aa06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010c9859f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
19  UIKit                               0x000000010a9c7550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
20  SpeedMeet_1.0                       0x0000000107cec163 main + 115
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ccdc145 start + 1
22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The loadobject method i'm calling in my viewWillAppear is supposed to clear the table view and then reload its data so i don't understand why this happens.
This is my implementation file:

```
@interface SMConfirmedMeetingsTableViewController ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *firstSectionArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *secondSectionArray;

@end

@implementation SMConfirmedMeetingsTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"MeetingObject";

    // The title for this table in the Navigation Controller.
    self.title = @"Confirmed meetings";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 20;
}
return self;
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *menuIcon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showMenu:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuIcon;

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SMShowMeetingTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SMShowMeetingTableViewCell"];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self loadObjects];
}


#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
[super objectsDidLoad:error];
if (error) {
    // something
}
// This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.firstSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.secondSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (PFObject *object in self.objects) {
    NSString *author = [object objectForKey:@"author"];
    if ([author isEqualToString: currentUser.username]) {
        //first section
        [self.firstSectionArray addObject:object];
    }else{
        //second section
        [self.secondSectionArray addObject:object];
    }
}

//add firstsection to the data array
NSDictionary *firstItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.firstSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
[self.dataArray addObject:firstItemsArrayDict];

//add Secondsection to the data array
NSDictionary *secondItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.secondSectionArray forKey:@"data"];
[self.dataArray addObject:secondItemsArrayDict];
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

PFQuery *queryAsAuthor = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[queryAsAuthor whereKey:@"user" equalTo: currentUser];

PFQuery *queryAsParticipant = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[queryAsParticipant whereKey:@"participants" equalTo:currentUser.username];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryAsAuthor, queryAsParticipant]];
[query whereKey:@"isAvailable" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[query orderByAscending:@"meetingDateAndTime"];

return query;
}


# pragma mark - Table view

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == 0) {
    return self.firstSectionArray.count;
}else
    return self.secondSectionArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// sections title text
if (section==0) {
    return @"Created by me";
}else return @"Created by others";
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SMShowMeetingTableViewCell";

SMShowMeetingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SMShowMeetingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
PFObject *obj = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.categoryLabel.text = [obj objectForKey:@"meetingCategoryString"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
cell.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[obj objectForKey:@"meetingDateAndTime"]];
cell.locationLabel.text = [obj objectForKey:@"meetingLocationString"];

return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NextPage";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading more meetings...",@"loading");
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
PFObject *obj = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
SMShowMeetingDetailViewController *meetingDetail = [[SMShowMeetingDetailViewController alloc]init];
meetingDetail.isMyMeetings = YES;
meetingDetail.meeting = obj;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:meetingDetail animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y < (self.view.bounds.size.height)) {
    if (![self isLoading]) {
        [self loadNextPage];
    }
}
}

@end
```

Comment: Try adding `[self.tableView reloadData];` to the end of `objectsDidLoad:`.

Comment: It works! So basically without that line the view controller was trying to reload the same table (i mean same number of sections and rows) but with different arrays...Thanks a lot, i was going crazy XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add `[self.tableView reloadData];` to the end of `objectsDidLoad:`. This will have the UI refresh itself with your updated data.